# pd.ExcelFile does not get the real sheet_names

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read in an Excel file with multiple sheets (s.t that all columns are strings). The below code works for that but it doen't get the correct sheet names. So my `dic_excel` which is a dictionary with all sheet names and the corresponding data has the following keys: 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', etc. But the actual names of the sheets are different. How do I get the actual names of the sheets?

```
dic_excel={}
excel = pd.ExcelFile(excel_path)
for sheet in excel.sheet_names:
    print(sheet)
    columns = excel.parse(sheet).columns
    converters = {col: str for col in columns}
    dic_excel[sheet] = excel.parse(sheet, converters=converters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is two ways to get the real names of your Excel sheets:

##### By using [**`pandas.DataFrame.keys`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.keys.html) with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

excel = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name=None)

dic_excel = df.keys()
```

*This will return a dictionnary of the sheetnames*

##### By using [**`Workbook.sheetname`**](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) with openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_path)

list_excel = wb.sheetnames
```

*This will return a list of the sheetnames*